# Show an indeterimante progress bar in a JDialog in a thread and run a task in another thread concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, runnable

When a user clicks a button, a long task of approximately 10 seconds will run. During this time I want to show a progress bar to the user. But the main thread has to wait for the worker thread to finish because the worker thread will set a variable that the main thread will use. If I don't wait the worker thread I will get a `NullPointerException` when using the variable. So after the worker thread finishes, I will also close the progress bar dialog.

When I wait for the worker thread using `join()` the progress bar dialog shows (interestingly without the progress bar though) and hangs there.

```
Thread runnable = new Thread() {

    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("thread basladi");
            threadAddSlaveReturnMessage = request.addSlave(
                ipField.getText(), passField.getText(), 
                nicknameField.getText());
            System.out.println("thread bitti");

        } catch (LMCTagNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

Thread runnable_progress = new Thread() {

    public void run() {

        JTextArea msgLabel;
        JDialog dialog;
        JProgressBar progressBar;
        final int MAXIMUM = 100;
        JPanel panel;

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, MAXIMUM);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        msgLabel = new JTextArea("deneme");
        msgLabel.setEditable(false);


        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        panel.add(msgLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        panel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(11, 11, 11, 11));

        dialog = new JDialog(Frame.getFrames()[0], "baslik", true);
        dialog.getContentPane().add(panel);
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setSize(500, dialog.getHeight());
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        msgLabel.setBackground(panel.getBackground());
    }
};

runnable.start();
System.out.println("runnable start");
runnable_progress.start();
System.out.println("progress start");
runnable.join();
System.out.println("runnable join");
runnable_progress.join();
System.out.println("progress join");


if (threadAddSlaveReturnMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
    fillInventoryTable(inventoryTable);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, messages.getString("centrum.addslavepanel.SUCCESS"), null, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
```

> "progress join"

doesn't get printed.

Comment: before going into details: the number one rule (related to concurrency) of Swing is that all component access _must_ happen on the EDT. Please read the relevant chapter in the tutorial referenced in the Swing tag :-)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. you have the issue with [Concurency is Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), your GUI is visible after all thread are done
2. is possible to moving with [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) (I'm talking about you code) but you have to

   - create and show [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), create once time and reuse this container
   - then to start `Thread`,
   - better could be from `Runnable#Thread`
   - output to the Swing GUI must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`
3. this is exactly job for using [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) and with [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) here. A short example :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package org.godel.nio;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author internet_2
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().doJob();
    }

    public void doJob() {

        JTextArea msgLabel;
        JProgressBar progressBar;
        final int MAXIMUM = 100;
        JPanel panel;

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, MAXIMUM);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        msgLabel = new JTextArea("deneme");
        msgLabel.setEditable(false);

        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        panel.add(msgLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        panel.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(11, 11, 11, 11));

        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.getContentPane().add(panel);
        dialog.setResizable(false);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setSize(500, dialog.getHeight());
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        msgLabel.setBackground(panel.getBackground());

        SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                // Close the dialog
                dialog.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List chunks) {
                // Here you can process the result of "doInBackGround()"
                // Set a variable in the dialog or etc.
            }

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                // Do the long running task here
                // Call "publish()" to pass the data to "process()"
                // return something meaningful
                return null;
            }
        };

        worker.execute();

    }
}
```

Edit : "[publish(](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish%28V...%29))" should be called in "doInBackground()" to pass the data to "process()".

Comment: +1 a little suggestion: you could mention to call publish (with the intermediate result) in doInBackground - because not doing so is a frequent error/misconception :-)

Comment: The same problem here. I have to wait the dojob function to complete. Because that function will set a variable. If I dont set it I get a null pointer exception. As you can see in my posted code, I am setting the threadAddSlaveReturnMessage variable in my long running task. If I dont wait it I get a nullpointer exception. If I wait it then the progress bar dialog appears without a progressbar :D and hangs there forever.

Comment: Btw waiting for the task to finish means using worker.get(); after worker.execute();

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answers already mentioned, `SwingWorker` is the way to go, if use want to use concurrency with Swing.
I found this [SwingWorker and ProgressBar tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SwingWorkerandProgressBar.htm) quite useful in understanding how it all works together.
Coming back to your actual problem: I assume you use a GUI, because you stated the user has to click a button. The question is, what is your "main thread" doing? Does it really have to run all the time? Doesn't look like it. Because you said the thread needs a variable which is set by another thread, which is a result of a user interaction. In short: Why does it need to run if it's dependent on a user interaction anyway?
 The usual way would be to first get all the data you need and then run the calculations or whatever. In your case, either run everything in a single background thread(set the variable first then do the rest), started by the ActionListener of your button or run the other thread **after** the thread where you set the variable has completed.
You could for example use the method `done()`, provided by `SwingWorker`, to launch the next task. Or if you really have to, you could wait in a loop for `task.isDone()`to return **true**. But don't forget to check for `isCancelled()` too.
Anyway, I think you should rethink your design. Because what I can see from the limited information provided looks overly complicated to me.